# Consulta dos tablas PHP

Tags: php

Tengo que hacer un listado de los reportes diarios que hacen los agentes comerciales y los administrativos de oficina en un único listado. Los reportes se guardan en la tabla PPR la cual tiene un id_user (si lo guarda un administrativo) y un id_agent (si hace el reporte el agente). Las tablas user y agent tienen cada una de ellas un id_user e id_agent respectivamente. El tema es que no tengo manera de que la consulta me salga bien ya que tanto en la tabla USER como en la AGENT tienen los mismos campos "nombre" y "apellidos"... me salen los reportes pero sin el nombre. Poniendo LEFT JOIN en ambos me sale el listado entero de reportes pero tan solo los nombres de los agentes,

```
 <?php
    $query = mysql_query("select * from ppr
    LEFT JOIN users ON users.user_id = ppr.id_user
    LEFT JOIN agent ON agent.agent_id = ppr.id_agent
    ORDER BY id_ppr DESC") or die(mysql_error());
    ?>
```

Tabla AGENTES

```
Id_agente | nombre | apellidos
```

Tabla USERS

```
Id_user | nombre | apellidos
```

Tabla REPORTES (PPR)

```
Id_reporte | Id_user | Id_agente | reporte
```

Ejemplo:

```
nombre apellidos | tipo      | reporte
-----------------+-----------+-------
Jose Poveda      | (agente)  | Reporte del día 4 de marzo....
Vicente Pérez    | (usuario) | Reporte del día 4 de marzo...
```

Comment: Puedes añadir un ejemplo de los campos de cada tabla  y del resultado que quieres obtener. Aunque creo saber  lo que necesitas encuentro ambigüedades en la pregunta, que me hacen dudar para dar una respuesta en una u otro dirección.

Comment: He editado la pregunta y he puesto un ejemplo de lo que quiero obtener

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es común encontrar que las tablas tengan los mismos nombres de columnas, normalmente lo que se tiene que hacer es identificar por separados los nombres de la columnas usando un alias. Por ej:

```
select a.nombre, b.nombre from tabla1 a, tabla2 b...
```

En el ejemplo anterior, tabla1 y tabla2 tienen una columna con el mismo nombre, pero para cada tabla se ha definido un alias, a y b respectivamente, de modo que ahora puede hacerse referencia a un campo particular de alguna de las 2 tablas por ej: *a.nombre*

Debes usar esta misma técnica en tu query para PHP, también deberías limitar el numero de campos a consultar y no usar *select **, especifica puntualmente el nombre de cada columna a utilizar.

Ahora, entiendo quieres cruzar las 3 tablas el query que planteas en esencia va bien

```
select * from ppr 
LEFT JOIN users ON users.user_id = ppr.id_user 
LEFT JOIN agent ON agent.agent_id = ppr.id_agent 
ORDER BY id_ppr DESC
```

Aplicando la sugerencia de los alias tendríamos algo así:

```
select p.*, u.nombres, u.apellidos, a.nombres, a.apellidos from ppr p 
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.user_id = p.id_user 
LEFT JOIN agent a ON a.agent_id = p.id_agent 
ORDER BY p.id_ppr DESC
```

Comment: Gracias por contestar, pero si quiero sacar los reportes que están en la tabla PPR? si selecciono solo las tablas agentes y users no me saldrán los reportes que están en la tabla PPR

Comment: @Vieira he actualizado la repuesta para complementar el query con tu necesidad espero te ayude

Comment: funciona pero me el problema lo tengo ahora cuando hago while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {, que al hacer echo $row['nombre'] y el echo de apellidos... por ahora me salen todos los reportes pero tan solo el nombre y apellidos de los agentes... de los usuarios no sale

Comment: @Vieira sugiero uses $row[0], es decir usar índices numéricos y no el nombre de la columna, por eso también sugerí que coloques el nombre de cada columna explícitamente en el select y no **select \***

Comment: Funciona a la perfección!!! muchas gracias @Jonnathan Q

Answer (score 0):

Realmente desde mi punto de vista tienes un error de diseño, los agentes y los usuarios deberian ser una unica tabla, ya que ambos son usuarios pero con diferentes roles. Tal como estan diseñanas las tablas te ves obligado a tener una tabla polimórfica (ppr) que rara vez es la mejor o unica solución, igualmente tal como lo tienes hecho, la tabla `ppr` va a tener si o si campos nulos en todos los registros con los que vas a tener que lidiar.

Dicho esto, podiamos evitar los registros nulos y optener un resultado mas limpio, utilizando UNION sobre la misma tabla, dejo un ejemplo:

```
/* creamos las tablas */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(Id integer PRIMARY KEY, nombre text, apellidos text);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS agent(Id integer PRIMARY KEY, nombre text, apellidos text);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ppr(Id integer PRIMARY KEY, id_user integer, id_agente integer, reporte text);

/* creamos filas en users */
INSERT INTO users VALUES(1,'Tomy', 'u pepe');
INSERT INTO users VALUES(2,'lili', 'a Ruko');

/* mostramos users */
SELECT * FROM users;


/* creamos filas en agent */
INSERT INTO agent VALUES(1,'Tom', 'ape joae');
INSERT INTO agent VALUES(2,'Lucy', 'acc tio');

/* mostramos agent */
SELECT * FROM agent;


/* creamos filas en ppr */

INSERT INTO ppr (id, id_user, id_agente, reporte) VALUES(1, 1, null, 'reporte user 1');
INSERT INTO ppr (id, id_user, id_agente, reporte) VALUES(2, null, 1, 'reporte agente 1');
INSERT INTO ppr (id, id_user, id_agente, reporte) VALUES(3, 2, null, 'reporte user 2');
INSERT INTO ppr (id, id_user, id_agente, reporte) VALUES(4, null, 2, 'reporte agente 2');



/* consulta UNION */

SELECT ppr.id, ppr.id_agente as user, 'agente' as tipo, agent.nombre, agent.apellidos, ppr.reporte FROM ppr
INNER JOIN agent ON agent.id = ppr.id_agente
WHERE id_agente IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT ppr.id, ppr.id_user as user, 'usuario' as tipo, users.nombre, users.apellidos, ppr.reporte FROM ppr 
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = ppr.id_user
WHERE id_user IS NOT NULL;
```

Resultado:

```
id | users | tipo    | nombre | apellidos | reporte
--------------------------------------------------
2  | 1     | agente  | Tom    | joae      | reporte agente 1
4  | 2     | agente  | Lucy   | acc tio   | reporte agente 2
1  | 1     | usuario | Tomy   | u pepe    | reporte user 1
3  | 2     | usuario | lili   | a Ruko    | reporte user 2
```